# Easy vs difficult distributions for sampling

Tags: distributions, sampling, markov-chain-montecarlo

Many sampling methods (e.g. [rejection sampling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rejection_sampling)) approach the sampling of a distribution $p$ as a problem of sampling from a **different** and somehow **easier** distribution $q$ and then correcting or accounting for the difference.

What makes some distributions easier or more difficult to sample than others?  How does one find an easy distribution to sample from, for a more difficult one?

Answer (score 6):

Computers can only do pseudo random sampling directly from a Uniform Distribution. Sampling from any other distribution requires some numerical transformations, such as [Inverse Transform Sampling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_transform_sampling).

This method, however, only allows to sample from distribution that have a defined Cumulative Distribution Function that can be inverted - and this is the case for most common distributions such as Normal, Exponential, Beta, etc. - these are the "easy" ones.

However, often times we might need to sample from a distribution whose CDF we cannot (or do not want to) compute, and we only have a Probability Density Function. This is indeed pretty standard, as you can often easily create a PDF with a desired shape, but do not have the means to compute its integral.

These cases, where you cannot use inverse transform sampling, are the "hard" ones, where you need to use Rejection or Importance sampling, with the help of a known distribution that you can sample from directly (via ITS).

Comment: I'm surprised computers can only do pseudo random sampling from a Uniform distribution. Wouldn't sampling form a Normal distribution be just as easy if not easier given how ubiquitous it is in physical phenomena (e.g. via CLT)? Also, what do you mean by ITS?

Comment: Sorry I wrote ITS for Inverse Transform Sampling :)

Comment: Well, from a numerical perspective it's not even that easy to generate random numbers (following a uniform), there's a lot of research that went into that. Then of course when you use R or Python you can sample from a normal or other distributions, but what's happening under the hood is indeed a transformation of data that is sampled uniformly

Comment: Thanks! and **why** is sampling from a **uniform** distribution easier? (any references or insight here would be great). What's special about it?

Comment: Well, the uniform distribution represents complete randomness, as any outcome has the same probability. This is the most general definition of "generating a random number", and the one that is most useful in a Computer Science setting, so that's where all the research for Pseudo Random Number Generators went into.

Comment: Thanks Davide, but if Normal distributions are more available "in the wild", couldn't one build a Uniform distribution from a Normal one, and also use those "native" Normal distributions to generate samples for all other distributions rather than the other way around? Wouldn't that lead to more natural (and easy to sample) randomness to start with?

Comment: Hard to answer to this as I am not particularly expert on Random Number Generation, you might want to ask a quesiton about this on StackOverflow, since it is a very CS specific topic. I do not think that it would be possible for a computer to sample directly from a normal. However, it would also not be efficient, as to use Inverse transform you need uniform number generation - so you would not be able to apply transformations and sample from all other distributions. I suggest you read some on the history of Pseudo Random Number Generators, it will probably answer your question better